# javascript img src path + variable concatentation

Tags: javascript

i cant seem to properly escape the JS variable to display an image(user avatar).
what is the correct way to do this? i need help guys.

```js
$.each(obj, function() {
     result = result + "<img class='user-pic' alt='' src="'assets/global/img/avatars/ + this['user_avatar'] + '"/> </a></div>";
      });
```

alt='' src="'assets/global/img/avatars/ + this['user_avatar'] + '"/> ";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be like:

```
$.each(obj, function(){
  result += "<img class='user-pic' alt='avatar' src='assets/global/img/avatars/"+this.user_avatar+"' /></a></div>";
});
```

To learn concatenation of Strings, imagine the outer quotes are pealed off. All the quotes inside that should be matching and the opposite of the outside quotes or escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepared strings to handle such situations in a better way

```
$.each(obj, function() {
  result += `<img class="user-pic" alt="" src="assets/global/img/avatars/${this['user_avatar'] || ""}" /> </a></div>`;
});
```